# What Steps are need to host a Website on Ubuntu using Apache2?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, webserver, websites, hosting

I successfully run one website on apache2 using a tutorial.
My second website, I can't reach locally, and I don't know why.

Here are the steps I follow :

1. copy my website to folder `/data/mywebsite`
2. create symlink to `/var/www/mywebsite`
3. configurate `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite`  like this :

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>         ServerAdmin me@localhost.de
>         ServerName localhost
>         DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite
>
>         <Directory /var/www/mywebsite>
>                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>                 AllowOverride All
>                 Order allow,deny
>                 Allow from all
>         </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

now I enable this page using apache2 and then restart apache2

```
sudo a2ensite mywebsite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but instead of my page, I only see my www folder.
I guess I linked something wrong. Is it necessary to have this slash `/` behind  `mywebsite` or something ?

I tried EVERYTHING that I can think of for some hours now.

I also tried to run it on different port and adding a Port to my `apache2 ports.conf`.
still no success.

Any advice would be most helpful.

Comment: You need to specify your server name for you second vhost. like `ServerName yoursecondwebsite.de`

Comment: i just saw that as well and addet it. still doesn't work

Comment: Ok so can you edit your question and give us your full `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite` content?

Comment: have you added the name of the new site under `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: I added my site 127.0.0.1 mywebsite  to hosts, yes. I also added Servername mywebsite to my config. thats my full content of that configuration :)) above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple sites on one Apache httpd server, you should post the complete configuration (both VirtualHost).

I'm going to post an example config of a two site Apache server, one which serves to www.example.com and one for www.example.org:

**file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/example-com**

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>
```

**file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/example-org**

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here ...

</VirtualHost>
```

If both your sites point to: localhost, only one site will show, one precedes the other, in other words, has a higher priority. That's wha the "ServerName" directive is there for. It will serve those who try to ener that ServerName.

So if you're only testing things on your localhost, just use the same VirtualHost and use subfolders. One site in: `/var/www/site1` and the other in `/var/www/site2`, and point your browser to: `http://localhost/site1` or `http://localhost/site2`.

Another solution if you don't want to have subfolders in your URL is to bypass your DNS lookup and just force some domain lookups throught the `/etc/hosts` file. Here is an example (You want to add to the 127.0.0.1 line at the end):

**file: /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example.com example.org
```

Your `/etc/hosts` file might look different, just remember to add the two domains to the end because as I explained earlier, Apache will only serve you one VirtualHost to the same ServerName.

For more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about this, but I played around for a few minutes to see how it works.

I think you were doing it right but, as already mentioned, you must add something like `ServerName www.site1.com` to the configuration (not *localhost*). Then enable the site, restart Apache, etc.

Also, as noted in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html : "Apache server does not magically cause DNS entries to be created for those host names. You *must* have the names in DNS, resolving to your IP address".

For local testing, you can edit the **/etc/hosts** file and add the site name (the *www.site1.com* used above) as alias for localhost, by changing the line that says `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `127.0.0.1 localhost www.site1.com` (replace `www.site1.com` by the name of your site). Then restart your browser and point it to the name of your site, to see if it works.

Or you could forget all these configurations and simply write *localhost/mywebsite* in your browser to access your site, but it seems it's not what you want.